# How do I have a character smack an object upwards from variou angles in box2d?

Tags: ios, box2d, cocos2d-x

Lets say I am trying to make a game that the character is weilding a frying pan and based on the angle of when the pan is swung the object will fly based on it, like if I have the pan scooping underneath the pancake it may fly forward or backwards depending on the position, like say this

This frame keeps the pancake stable and does not move far from the character or pan
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/738tL.gif

This angle has it moving away from the pan and can potential fly past the character.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXSBw.jpg

I'm trying to make the game in cocos2d

What would I need to do to the character to have him do this, how can I script his "pan" from being the collision force that flips the pancake and not the whole character colliding with the pancake.

Comment: i wouldn't use physics for this to begin with, way too much tweaking to get it right and looking good/realistic

Comment: So what exactly can I use? This is an example of what I'm trying to do http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/622566

Comment: Velocity (a CGPoint vector) integrated every frame (ie position.x = position.x + velocity.x + gravity.x etc), then CGRectIntersectsRect for collision detection. Gravity is also a CGPoint with fixed values, ie {0, -5}

Comment: I know this is very late, but are there any tutorials that show me how to integrate it in Cocos2d 3.0? Like how to integrate every frame how would I write the over all code and apply it to my objects.